# Powershell wait for keypress

Tags: powershell, wait, keypress

I would like to make this script to pause after typing "Hello this is a test" automatically and after pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key it should wait for <kbd>F2</kbd> key to be pressed.
 How can that be done?

```
function wait {
param([int]$stop = 3)
Start-Sleep -seconds $stop
}


[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")
& "$env:Windir\notepad.exe"
$a = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Notepad"}
wait

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("Hello this is a test")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
wait

# here I want something like wait for F2 key to be pressed
# after the F2 key was pressed I want the script to continue

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("This is After the key was pressed")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")

exit
```

Answer (score 3):

The following will loop until F2 is pressed, with a prompt to the user.

```
do{ echo "Press F2";$x = [System.Console]::ReadKey() } while( $x.Key -ne "F2" )
```

Comment: Seems to be in an infinite loop

Comment: I just pasted that line into a prompt, and no infinite loop

Comment: This is really good, but in addition to the `F2`, how can we also break out of that loop if a maximum time is reached (i.e. 30 seconds)?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a modified version of your script that achieves what you want. Keep in mind that this will not work in the PowerShell Integrated Scripting Editor (ISE).

```
$Wait = 3;

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")
& "$env:Windir\notepad.exe"
$a = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Notepad"}
Start-Sleep -Seconds $Wait;

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("Hello this is a test")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Seconds $Wait;

while ([System.Console]::ReadKey().Key -ne [System.ConsoleKey]::F2) { };

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("This is After the key was pressed")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")

exit
```